# Как в VB.NET вызвать функцию с возвращаемым типом Generic?

Tags: generics, vb.net

Есть к примеру такая сигнатура, как ее вызвать?

```
Public Function Example(Of T)() As T
```

Comment: `Example(of Integer)()`. Вместо `Integer` - нужный Вам тип

Comment: Вы же вроде давно с `VB.NET` работаете. Только сейчас добрались до дженериков?)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov да так оно и есть... Когда одновременно пишешь на нескольких языках, не всегда удается познавать новое, особенно если не знаешь что оно есть и не знаешь за чем оно)

Comment: ну Вы даёте) Удачного освоения сией дивной возможности языка!)